# Is there a configuration in VIM that can prevent VIM from opening an encrypted file?

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to configure VIM so that when an attempt is made to edit a file encrypted by VIM, or to encrypt a file, VIM would warn or refuse such action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should build your custom version of Vim excluding this feature (`FEAT_CRYPT`) completely. This is the most complete and error-prone solution.

To make Vim fail on attempt to write encrypted data you can try something along those lines

```
augroup example | au!
    autocmd BufWritePre * if !empty(&key) | throw "No encryption allowed here!" | endif
augroup end
```